# Laravel 'boot' function is not firing

Tags: laravel

I have the following in an eloquent model

```
class Bucket extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    protected $appends = ['slug'];

    public function __construct(){
        $this->key = substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 24);
    }

    public static function boot(){

        dd('check');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    public function getSlugAttribute(){
        return slugify($this->name);
    }

}
```

However I'm able to read and update the model with no problem. I was under the impression boot was supposed to be called every time a model was instantiated, is that wrong?

Here's one of the controllers I use to view all the buckets

```
public function index()
{
    return Auth::user()->buckets;
}
```

Comment: boot() does get called whenever you instantiate a model. Can you post some code?
What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @cecilozaur I added some more code. I'm on 4.2.16

Comment: i think the problem is your __construct method. The boot function won't be executed if you have your own constructor.
Laravel eloquent constructor call the boot function - so this gives a conflict i guess.

Comment: yes @goldlife is right, you need to call parent::__construct() in you constructor. or call bootIfNotBooted()

Comment: Ahh, ok. I'll  just move over to my constructor function, thanks!

Comment: Btw you can also use `Str::random(24)` to get a random alphanumeric string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your constructor, try calling

```
parent::__construct();
```

Comment: and if you are using attributes as in `public function __construct(array $attributes = [])`, then you would need to `parent::__construct($attributes);`